# How do I delete a remote symlink to a branch in git?

Tags: git, symlink

I have git repo as follows:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/m/branch_a -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I want to delete the remote symlink to master there without deleting master. I have tried:

```
$ git remote -v prune --dry-run
```

this does nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a "symlink" (not since git added support for Windows), it's a "symbolic reference" (though this amounts to the same thing).

The name of the remote is whatever appears after `remotes/`, so in this case, the remote is named `m`.

If the symbolic reference exists in your repository, and using `--prune` (on either `git fetch m` or `git remote update m`) does not discard it, that means it's (still) present on remote `m`.  Even if you delete it manually on your end, it will come back when you pick up the latest information from that remote.

The cure, then, is to delete it on the remote (and then run `git fetch -p m` again).

If remote `m` no longer exists (or never did exist) and this symbolic reference is left over from something odd you did (or some weird bug), you can simply delete it:

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/m/branch_a
```